# AutoComplete using JSON AJAX JQUERY in C# MVC

Tags: c#, html, json, ajax, model-view-controller

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult UniversalSearch()
        {
            List<UniversalSearchBar> EmployeeDetails = new List<UniversalSearchBar>();
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Abishek", EmployeeID = "SF2532", EmailID = "abishek@syncfusion.com" });
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Bharath", EmployeeID = "SF2010", EmailID = "bharath@syncfusion.com" });
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Roshini", EmployeeID = "SF3052", EmailID = "roshini@syncfusion.com" });
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Kathir", EmployeeID = "SF5572", EmailID = "kathir@syncfusion.com" });
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Ragu", EmployeeID = "SF7582", EmailID = "ragu@syncfusion.com" });
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Sri", EmployeeID = "SF3456", EmailID = "sri@syncfusion.com" });
            EmployeeDetails.Add(new UniversalSearchBar() { EmployeeName = "Guru", EmployeeID = "SF2890", EmailID = "guru@syncfusion.com" });

            var Employees = EmployeeDetails;
            return Json(Employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<select class="form-control" id="searchFilterList" style="width:200px!important" onchange="changeSearchBarID()">
    <option value="employeeName">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="employeeID">Employee ID</option>
    <option value="emailID">Email ID</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="EmployeeNameSearch"; style="max-width:800px!important">
```

**Script**

```
var autocomplete;
$(function () {
    // declaration
    var options = {
        //how to render json data from controller here?//
    };
    $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete({
        dataSource: options,
        width: "800",
        template: '<div class="txt"> ${EmployeeName} </div>' +
                  '<div class="txt"> ${EmailID} </div>'
    });
});
```

Here I have Dropdown with three category 1) Employee Name 2) Employee Id 3) Email Id. 
In default when i type something in search bar it should display employee name in suggesion along with email id.

And if i select **employee Id** in category and type something in search it should find employee name related typing **EMPLOYEE ID** and display Employee name and email id below in suggestion

And if i select **email Id** in category and type something in search it should find employee name related typing **EMAIL ID** and display Employee name and email id below in suggestion

Since i'm new to this please some one explain me clearly.

Should i add something in routeconfig when i use this.

Comment: please add an WebApi for this kind needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems using this -> https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejautocomplete

1- There is  http://help.syncfusion.com/js/autocomplete/data-binding#odata
it seems they use their DataManager

```
     ej.DataManager
```

you could easyly cutomize this sample...

2- As far as i can see from document, there is a parameter named data source,

```
   dataSource: window.carList,value:"Austin-Healey"
```

I would think like this ;

```
   dataSource : function(){
       // someAjaxStuff here 
       // by your search parameters
       // ps.
       // also dont forget it is working async... 

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get JSON data from the server like below and use it as a autocomplete param:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.get("URL_TO_CONTROLLER_ACTION", function (jsonOptions) {
            $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete({
                dataSource: jsonOptions,
                width: "800",
                template: '<div class="txt"> ${EmployeeName} </div>' +
                          '<div class="txt"> ${EmailID} </div>'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It seems, question is about to dynamic jsonOptions 
so this fine for static seach/auto complete
but
When parameter changed you have to rebind autocomplete again.
ej.DataManager seems better for thi spurpose.